# Join two lines in Vim without moving the cursor

Tags: vim

How can I join two lines in Vim and **leave the cursor in its original position** instead of it jumping to the merge point?

For example, take the the following two lines with the cursor at the position indicated by the caret:

```
this is ^line one
this is line two
```

Merging by <kbd>J</kbd> produces:

```
this is line one ^this is line two
```

How can I produce:

```
this is ^line one this is line two
```

I have tried things like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and variations of <kbd>''</kbd>. None of these seem to work. They go to the beginning of the line, not to the original cursor position.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another approach that wouldn't stomp on marks would be this:

```
:nnoremap <silent> J :let p=getpos('.')<bar>join<bar>call setpos('.', p)<cr>
```

Much more verbose but it prevents you from losing a mark.

- `:nnoremap` - Non-recursive map
- `<silent>` - Do not echo anything when the mapping is pressed
- `J` - Key to map
- `:let p=getpos('.')` - Store cursor position
- `<bar>` - Command separator (`|` for maps, see `:help map_bar`)
- `join` - The ex command for normal's `J`
- `<bar>` - ...
- `call setpos('.', p)` - Restore cursor position
- `<cr>` - Run the commands

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!  I just one more request, though.  Could you quickly explain what the piece after the J is doing?

Comment: This is a silly general vimscript question but I feel like it's appropriate: What's the scope that is being polluted with the variable `p`? Is this something that can potentially cause a strange configuration bug? Is there a good reason not to name it something a lot more specific (and less prone to variable name collision) than `p`?

Comment: Also, in all my armchair travels I've never once been exposed to `<Bar>`. Thanks for showing me. I have many vimrc snippets that implement functions due to the need to run multiple commands off of a bind, this makes it possible to inline a lot of these binds.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like:

```
:nnoremap <F2> mbJ`b
```

This assigns the following actions to the <kbd>F2</kbd> key:

1. That is, create a mark (<kbd>m</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, but **NOTE** if you had set previously the `b` mark, than it gets overwritten!)
2. <kbd>J</kbd>oin the lines
3. Jump back to the previous mark (<kbd>`</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>)

Comment: May be worth pointing out, in case it doesn't occur to someone, that this will overwrite the `b` mark if it was set.

Comment: If I wanted to end up at the beginning of the line, this would work.  However that's not what.

Comment: no, the single quote ' takes you to beginning of line, the backtick ` takes you to exact position

Comment: ah, can't tell the difference between the two in my browser.  Thank you @Alexander for using words and not assuming I could see the difference.

Comment: Instead of using the b mark, why not just use the \` (backtick) mark?  `nnoremap <F2> m\`J\`\``

Comment: @karategeek6 and what is the advantage of using that? But to answer your question: I used to use `b` because that is [under my thumb](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYYTLJ8YHi4) and I don't use backtick because I'm using an international keyboard layout and backtick requires `left ALT (Gr) + 7` and that's unconfortable.

Comment: @Zsolt The backtick mark marks the position before the latest jump, so it makes logical sense.  It also prevents the clobbering of other marks which may already be set.  I often use the letter marks as bookmarks to various parts of the document I am working on.  I can't rely on any of the letter marks being available.  In the end, however, the mark used is really just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Utility function that you can use for other purposes:

```
" Utility function that save last search and cursor position
" http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/preserve-a-vim-function-that-keeps-your-state/
" video from vimcasts.org: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace
if !exists('*Preserve')
    function! Preserve(command)
        try
            " Preparation: save last search, and cursor position.
            let l:win_view = winsaveview()
            let l:old_query = getreg('/')
            silent! execute 'keepjumps ' . a:command
         finally
            " Clean up: restore previous search history, and cursor position
            call winrestview(l:win_view)
            call setreg('/', l:old_query)
         endtry
    endfunction
endif
```

The advantage of the solution using the above function is: Does not occupy any register

```
" Join lines without moving the cursor (gJ prevent adding spaces between lines joined)
nnoremap J :call Preserve("exec 'normal! J'")<cr>
nnoremap gJ :call Preserve("exec 'normal! gJ'")<cr>
```

BTW: Two more examples on how you can use the *Preserve* function -

```
" Remove extra spaces at the end of the line

    fun! CleanExtraSpaces()
        call Preserve('%s/\s\+$//ge')
    endfun
    com! Cls :call CleanExtraSpaces()
    au! BufwritePre * :call CleanExtraSpaces()

" Reident the whole file

    call Preserve('exec "normal! gg=G"')
```